# Get the value of a variable from another

Tags: perl

Can you assist me in determing correct $string = line to end up with partial_phone containing 4165867111?

```
sub phoneno {
my ($string) = @_;
$string =~  s/^\+*0*1*//g;
return $string;
}

my $phone = "<sip:+4165867111@something;tag=somethingelse>";

my $partial_phone = phoneno($phone);
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: sorry, just corrected my post, 4165867111 part of initial string

Comment: Make sure to either escape the @ in $phone or to use single instead of double quotes. Otherwise Perl will interpolate the (non-existent) array `@something` and you'll end up with `<sip:+4165867111;tag=somethingelse>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your substitution starts with a `^`, which means it won't perform substitution unless the rest of your pattern matches the start of your string.

There are lots of ways to do this. How about

```
my ($partial) = $phone =~ /([2-9]\d+)/;
return $partial;
```

This returns any string of digits that doesn't begin with a 0 or 1.

Comment: thanks for your help, it is actually a phone number, that may might with 1 or 0, is there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

```
$string =~ s{
    \A          # beginning of string
    .+          # any characters
    \+          # literal +
    (           # begin capture to $1
        \d{5,}  # at least five digits
    )           # end capture to $`
    \@          # literal @
    .+          # any characters
    \z          # end of string
}{$1}xms;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will capture all digits preceding the `@`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub phoneno {
    my ($string) = @_;
    my ($phoneNo) = $string =~ /(\d+)\@/;
    return $phoneNo;
}

my $phone = '<sip:+4165867111@something;tag=somethingelse>';

my $partial_phone = phoneno($phone);

print $partial_phone;
```

Output:

```
4165867111
```